# How to center a form with fieldset inside a div?

Tags: html, css, forms

I am trying to create a form that looks like this wireframe that I made

[image: ideal form]

I am currently here though

[image: current progress]

My code is as follows

**HTML**

```
<div id="accountRequest">
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Please sign up here </legend>
      <label>First Name</label>
      <input type="text" />
      <label>Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" />
      <label>Display Name</label>
      <input type="text" />
      <label>Password</label>
      <input type="text" />
      <label>Tell us about yourself (optional)</label>
      <textarea rows="3"></textarea>   
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="text" />
      <div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Create Account</button>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
#accountRequest {
  background-color:#fff;
  border-radius:3px;
  width:330px;
  border: 1px #333 solid; 
}
#accountRequest form { 
  width:282px; 
}
#accountRequest fieldset { border-radius:3px;
  max-width: 300px;
}
#accountRequest form input, 
#accountRequest form textarea { 
  width: 300px; 
}
```

Not a duplicate of [Center a form using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574303/center-a-form-using-css) because that addresses centering across the entire page.

Also not a duplicate of [Center a div that contains a contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683863/center-a-div-that-contains-a-contact-form) because that form does not contain a fieldset. And the fieldset here seems to present some unexpected problems.

Comment: no jsFiddle, no jsBin :(

Comment: Here, this should get them started: http://jsfiddle.net/JvF9t/ :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your inputs are too wide. Try:

```
#accountRequest form input,
#accountRequest form textarea { 
   width: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing 96% and `margin:0;` . I think you are right, But apparently I did something hacky elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this worked the best but still seems hacky.

```
#accountRequest {
  background-color:#fff;
  border: 1px #333 solid; 
  border-radius:3px;
  height:540px;
  width:360px;
}
#accountRequest form { 
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 96%;
}
#accountRequest fieldset { border-radius:3px; }
#accountRequest form label { margin:auto; width:100%; }
#accountRequest form input, 
#accountRequest form textarea { margin:auto; width: 96%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've sorted it out but I've changed the widths to percentages. These would be better in my opinion compared to fixed pixels. I used margin: 0 auto to center up the entire form and its elements

```
#accountRequest {
  background-color:#fff;
  border-radius:3px;
  width:100%;
  border: 1px #333 solid; 
}
#accountRequest form { 
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#accountRequest fieldset { 
 border-radius:3px;
 width: 100%;
}
#accountRequest form input, 
#accountRequest form textarea { 
  width: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: I completely agree with you about percentages instead of fixed widths. This is my first site that I am not only not doing as responsive. I tried your suggestion. But the form `#accountRequest` does need to be a fixed width as it is a container. I ended up making `<form>` 96% and `<fieldset>` and inner elements 92% which worked for my case. Thank you so much for the suggestion.